# My mom was once cheating . Is it compulsory for me to show love and care her

Tags: zina, parents

Assalamu alaikum ,I am 20yrs old now.i am from india ,My father is still working in Riyadh and he visits us 2years once and also he privide us whatever my family needs. when i was 11 i found out my mom cheating with neighbor who was 24yrs old at that time . I found out when they talking double meaning & flirting in front of me . Also found messages (text) that man sent to my mother [ i wont live without you , talk to me , pick my phone ] . And even she went to his marriage 2yrs later and present him Table fan . Now she has no connection with him . I have not told this to anyone till now. I think she regret what she had done and even she prays and read quran now
The question is ...  Now she is suffering ill and i have no sympathy or empathy for her. Is it compulsory for me to show love and care towards her .

Answer (score 2):

She was unfaithful to your father, but ultimately didn't follow through with it and now she has repented. Even if they engage in shirk it is taught to show kindness to parents. Cheating on her husband is a comparatively minor transgression.

> But if they (both) strive with you to make you join in worship with Me
> others that of which you have no knowledge, then obey them not; but
> behave with them in the world kindly, and follow the path of him who
> turns to Me in repentance and in obedience. Then to Me will be your
> return, and I shall tell you what you used to do.
>
> https://quran.com/31/15

> Narrated Asma 'bint Abi Bakr: During the period of the peace treaty of
> Quraish with Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), my mother, accompanied by her
> father, came to visit me, and she was a pagan. I consulted Allah's
> Messenger (ﷺ), "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! My mother has come to me and
> she desires to receive a reward from me, shall I keep good relation
> with her?" He said, "Yes, keep good relation with her."
>
> Sahih al-Bukhari 3183 https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3183